# Why does this Geotools Java reprojection to WGS-84/4326 cause offset?

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am using the block of code below. I am reading in a geotif with a UTM zone projection and converting it to 4326. I am pulling out certain multiband values and creating a new raster, when I plot the new raster in ArcMap or QGis, the two don't line up. Can anyone tell me if I am doing this transform correctly?

Here is some additional information as requested
the offset is about 85 meters according to QGis
Geotools version is 11.1

[image]

```
ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY
            .createValue();
    policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);

    // this will basically read 4 tiles worth of data at once from the disk...
    ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();

    // Setting read type: use JAI ImageRead (true) or ImageReaders read methods (false)
    ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
    useJaiRead.setValue(true);

    GridCoverage2D image = new GeoTiffReader(f).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
    /**
     * reproject to WGS84
     */
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    image = (GridCoverage2D) Operations.DEFAULT.resample(image, targetCRS);

    GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
    WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
```

Comment: Can you say how much the offset is? Version of geotools? Source data? Is the image oriented correctly after reprojection?

Comment: just updated, as for the source data, it is a geotiff multiband from DigitalGlobe, and I dont' render the image after reprojection, I convert choice pixels to points and then convert those points to raster.

Comment: What exactly was the source projection?

Comment: this is what the qgis meta data tab reports 
+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: @iant this is what the qgis meta data tab reports +proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs. BTW, if I reproject the image first using arcGis, then run my process without the reproject piece, the images line up.